# Thickness of the Cartesian product of two complete graphs

Tags: graph-theory

The Cartesian product of graphs $G$ and $H$ is a graph with vertex set $V(G\mathbin{\square} H)=V(G)×V (H)$, that is the set $\{(g,h)\mid g\in G, h\in H\}$. The edge set of $G\mathbin{\square}H$ consists of all pairs $(g,h)(g′,h′)$ of vertices with $gg′\in E(G)$ and $h=h′$ or $hh′\in E(H)$ and $g=g′$. Also, the thickness, $\theta(G)$, of a graph $G$ is the minimum number of planar spanning subgraphs into which $G$ can be decomposed.

I'm working on a paper where there are only a few graphs left and I want to know if these graphs have a thickness of 2 or not. These graphs are as the following:

1. $K_4\mathbin{\square}K_7$
2. $K_5\mathbin{\square}K_7$
3. $K_5\mathbin{\square}K_5$

where $K_n$ is a complete graph on $n$ vertices.
I guess that $\theta (K_4\mathbin{\square}K_7)=\theta (K_5\mathbin{\square}K_5)=2$ and $\theta(K_5\mathbin{\square}K_7)=3$, but I can't prove it.

Comment: So you are not interested in $\theta(K_5\mathbin{\square} K_6)$, right?

Comment: No. Just knowing the thickness of the graphs I said is important for me.

Comment: Can $K_7$ be partitioned into two outerplanar graphs?

Comment: I think the answer to my own question is "no".

Comment: @BrendanMcKay: No, $K_7$ is decomposed into three outerplanar subgraphs.

Comment: I got that $\theta (K_5\mathbin{\square}K_5)=2$. If someone can get the thickness of the other two graphs, I can add that person to the paper.